# select results from one date field compared to another + 24 hours

Tags: sql, datetime, sap-ase

I need to pull values from one table that are only 24 hours from the date in another table in sybase ase 15.5.

Here is my wrong code:

```
SELECT p_generaldata.admissiontime,*
 FROM   Patient.dbo.P_MonVals P_MonVals 
               INNER JOIN Patient.dbo.P_GeneralData P_GeneralData 
               ON P_MonVals.PatientID=P_GeneralData.PatientID
where  p_generaldata.admissiontime < P_MonVals.entertime +1
order by p_generaldata.patientid ASC
```

Im trying to return all rows in p_monvals, where the entertime in that table is less than 24 hours after the admissiontime.

> the error im getting is INT is not compatible with DATETIME

Any help greatly appreciated

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look a the [`DateAdd`](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1530/doc/html/san1278453012069.html) function, and add a day to the `entertime`

Example from docs:

Adds one day to a date:

```
declare @a date
select @a = "apr 12, 9999"
select dateadd(dd, 1, @a)
```

In your case...

```
...
where  p_generaldata.admissiontime < dateadd(dd, 1, P_MonVals.entertime)
```

Comment: I added your line but it still returned rows from monvals that were three days after the admission date. what im after is admission time of say 14/04/2014 20:00:00, it will return rows from monvals with an entertime between 14/04/2014 20:00:00 and 15/04/2014 20:00:00 , so its not all results from the next day, its 24 hours from the admission time. thanks so much

Comment: Can't you use `dateadd`, using hours instead of days in that case?

Comment: thanks mate. the solution was in dateadd....where  P_MonVals.entertime between p_generaldata.admissiontime and dateadd(hh, 24, p_generaldata.admissiontime).... thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use function `dateadd` to sum 1 day in your date time:

```
dateadd(dd, 1, P_MonVals.entertime)
```

Reference: [Sybase dateadd function](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36271.1570/html/blocks/X10609.htm).

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the [dateadd](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36271.1550/html/blocks/X10609.htm) function:

```
SELECT p_generaldata.admissiontime, *
FROM Patient.dbo.P_MonVals P_MonVals 
INNER JOIN Patient.dbo.P_GeneralData P_GeneralData 
ON P_MonVals.PatientID=P_GeneralData.PatientID
WHERE p_generaldata.admissiontime < DATEADD(dd, 1, P_MonVals.entertime)
ORDER BY p_generaldata.patientid ASC
```